# Culture-sensitive string sorting

Tags: javascript, c#

In my .NET c# code, I would like to sort some strings - specifically, currently my app support two locales, English and Chinese (possibly more in future). And I would like to return a list of names to the client side.

right before the list of strings is returned to the client, I would like to sort the strings.

I basically need to do what Javascript does for "localeCompare". Is that something that can be done on the C# code? I found some thing related to CultureInfo, but it seems to me that I need to set that value dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `Sort` overload, accepting an `IComparer`, that can be used culture aware.

Your client should pass it‘s desired language via [Accept-Language request-header](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) when requesting the API  or it could be a claim or setting for the logged in user.

Here is an example within your controller on the API side:

```
var requestLanguage = "zh-Hans"; // pass the correct one

namesList.Sort(StringComparer.Create(new CultureInfo(requestLanguage), true));
```

The `true` parameter indicates that it’s case sensitive. You can find the [cultureinfo on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8).

[Docs about the String Comparer.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)